# gitlab gui does not show jenkinsfile report back from stage test

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a pipeline for a project where we use gitlab and jenkins as external for builds and tests.

I can't find why the report back from jenkins does show up in gitlab gui as Jobs and not in the tab Tests.

See picture:
[image]

I run this as a jenkinspipeline with a webhook from gitlab.

This is how my Jenkinsfile look, I suspect the problem to be here but I am new to jenkinsfiles.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
       stage ('Example Build') {
          steps {
             echo 'Notify GitLab build pending'
             updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'pending'
             sh 'gcc -Wall helloWorld.c -o helloWorld'
             updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'build', state: 'success'
          }
       }
       stage ('Example Test') {
           steps {
               echo 'Notify GitLab tests pending'
               updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'Tests', state: 'pending'
               sh './startTest.sh'
               updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'Tests', state: 'success'

           }
       }
    }
 }
```